# How can I install ngx_http_image_filter_module to an existing nginx installation?

Tags: nginx, installation

I am trying to install [ngx_http_image_filter_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) to an existing nginx installation I have read that now nginx supports [dynamic modules](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/dynamic-modules/).

I have tried:

```
./configure --with-http_image_filter_module
```

But it doesn't work, I was wondering if or how I could do it.